How to make the cells of this table editable on second click
On first click the focus should come on the cell on the second click  , focus should come on the input box...
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(null);
  // const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState("");

  const [array, setArray] = useState(Array.from({ length: 4 }, () =>
      Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => ({
        color: "",
        text: "",
      })
    ))
  )

  function selectCell(row,col){

    console.log("Selected Cell ==>",row,col);
    console.log("CurrentIndex ==>",currentIndex);
    setCurrentIndex({row:row,col:col})

  }

  function handleText(text,row,col){
    console.log("Text =>",text)
    let newArray=[...array];
    newArray[row][col].text=text;
    setArray(newArray);
    console.log("Array =>",array)
  }

  function changeColor(color){
    if (currentIndex) {
        const newArray = [...array];
          newArray[currentIndex.row][currentIndex.col].color = color;
          setArray(newArray);
         }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
        <button onClick={() => changeColor("red")}>Red</button>
        <button onClick={() => changeColor("blue")}>Blue</button>
        <button onClick={() => changeColor("green")}>Green</button>
      </div>


      <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
        {array.map((arr, rowIndex) => (
          <div key={rowIndex} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            {arr.map((item, colIndex) => (
              <div
                onClick={()=>selectCell(rowIndex,colIndex)}
                key={colIndex}
                style={{  width: 100, height:50, margin:2, display:'flex',alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",
                   backgroundColor: item.color,
                  border: currentIndex && currentIndex.row === rowIndex && currentIndex.col === colIndex ? "2px solid black" : "1px solid black"
                }}
                >
                {currentIndex && currentIndex.row==rowIndex && currentIndex.col == colIndex ? 
                   <input
                   type="text"
                   style={{width: 90, height:40, backgroundColor:item.color }}
                    value={item.text}
                   readOnly={!( currentIndex && currentIndex.row === rowIndex && currentIndex.col === colIndex)}
                   onChange={(e)=>handleText(e.target.value,rowIndex,colIndex)}
                 /> 

                : `${item.text}`}
               
                
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
  

This is my code and want to know what I am doing wrong
...am I setting the currentIndex state wrongly...
Currently when clicking on the cell , on the second or third time , then the input box become editable but , it should become editable on second click....
I have doubts that I have done some issue in setting currentIndex but unable to figure out what is wrong.

It's not clear what you should achieve. By running your code I see that clicking on a cell focuses it. Clicking again on the same cell focuses on the input. Clicking on a different cell starts the journey again with focus on cell, a second click will focus the input. Is that not correct?

@undefinederror , thanks for the response  ,
but I was not sure if that is the correct approach for setting the currentIndex

you mean setCurrentIndex({row:row,col:col})? Nothing wrong with that.
